# overlay window implementation in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my wp8 phone app, I want to show overlay window when a particular action is completed based on certain data a(eg: summary, or game level details).

Is there way to do this in c#?

Comment: You can use pop-up control to show an overlay Window.for more detail see http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-get-user-input-from-a-popup-in-windows-phone

Comment: found this link for overlay popup window
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27742.windows-phone-create-simple-overlay-with-usercontrol-in-windows-phone.aspx